# Python 2.7 Improving recursive pollard rho factorization with memoize

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, memoization

I am trying to revamp a function that uses the Pollard Rho method to factor an integer but my attempt at using memoize has had no improvement in being able to factor a specific number (N=7331117) that this function should be able to facotr.

Before attempt:

```
import fractions

def pollard_Rho(n):

    def f(xn):
        if xn == 0:
            return 2
        return f(xn - 1) ** 2 + 1
    i = 0
    x = f(i)
    y = f(f(i))
    d = fractions.gcd(abs(x - y), n)
    while d == 1:
        i = i + 1
        d = fractions.gcd(abs(x - y), n)
    root1 = d
    root2 = n / d
    print i + 1
    return (root1, root2)
```

memoize attempt:

```
def pollard_Rho(n):

    class memoize:
        def __init__(self, function):
            self.function = function
            self.memoized = {}

        def __call__(self, *args):
            try:
                return self.memoized[args]
            except KeyError:
                self.memoized[args] = self.function(*args)
                return self.memoized[args]

    @memoize
    def f(xn):
        if xn == 0:
            return 2
        return f(xn - 1) ** 2 + 1
    i = 0
    x = f(i)
    y = f(f(i))
    d = fractions.gcd(abs(x - y), n)
    while d == 1:
        i = i + 1
        d = fractions.gcd(abs(x - y), n)
    root1 = d
    root2 = n / d
    print i + 1
    return (root1, root2)
```

Now neither code produces any errors but both codes also do produce any results.

The output of

```
print pollard_Rho(7331117)
```

should be (641, 11437) (I know this because of another factorization function I have written) but what actually happens is the code runs through 3 iterations of the while loop and nothing happens afterwards. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Sorry for the vague question, does anyone have any suggestions on improving the the codes ability to factor in general? Maybe by a method more efficient than a recursive function? 7331116 and 7331118 factor perfectly fine and only 7331117 seems to be a tough nut to crack so far using this method.

Its possible I didn't use memoize right because even with looking at at on of stackoverflow examples I don't really understand how to use it. It seems every single instance of it I came across was drastically different.

Comment: I can't see how that `while` loop can possibly work. Either it runs forever or not at all, since you're calling the same side-effect free function with the same arguments on each pass.

Comment: @Blckknght, I it just takes a long time. I think, complexity of the function is O(2^N). So function definitely needs a cache.

Comment: @Blckknght For some reason I got confused when editing the while loop into this into stack overflow, I might have gotten confused with my sage version of the code also. Thank you for point that out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your algorithm does not work for some reason. In order to see what is going on I went to wikipedia site of the algorithm and implemented regular version from there and it worked without a problem. Than I replaced my g function with your recursive version and I got following error

```
  File "rho.py", line 25, in f_fun
    return 2 if xn == 0 else f_fun(xn - 1) ** 2 + 1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

It seems like you cannot implement this with a regular recursion. I would suggest to convert your recursion to a fold or a generator.

Here is the code I tried:

https://gist.github.com/huseyinyilmaz/73c1ac42b2a20d24d3b5

UPDATE:
Here is your version with cache, it still have maximum depth problem. (python 2 implementation)
https://gist.github.com/huseyinyilmaz/bb26ac172fbec4c655d3

Comment: Thank you for trying. This problem has me utterly burned out. (this for a non programming class) and I thought I was at least close but I have no idea what folds are or generators in Python or SageMath..

Comment: I was just doing some testing and my code doesn't even work properly for numbers other than the one(7331117) I was trying to get to work. ....................................